Helm Upgrade Failed: Another Operation in Progress
Encountered an issue while running two pipelines in parallel, leading to a Helm upgrade failure with the following error message:
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: another operation (install/upgrade/rollback) is in progress
helm.go:84: [debug] another operation (install/upgrade/rollback) is in progress
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action.init
    <autogenerated>:1
runtime.doInit1
    runtime/proc.go:7176
runtime.doInit
    runtime/proc.go:7143
runtime.main
    runtime/proc.go:253
runtime.goexit
    runtime/asm_amd64.s:1695
UPGRADE FAILED
main.newUpgradeCmd.func2
    helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/upgrade.go:240
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.0/command.go:983
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.0/command.go:1115
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.0/command.go:1039
main.main
    helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/helm.go:83
runtime.main
    runtime/proc.go:271
runtime.goexit
    runtime/asm_amd64.s:1695
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1


It appears that one of the operations is stuck in a pending state. I've accessed the shell of the pods, but I can't find helm or kubectl commands available. How can I diagnose what is stuck in the pending state and proceed with the upgrade?
Tried accessing the pod shells to troubleshoot, but essential commands are missing.
Any guidance on how to resolve this issue or identify the pending operation would be greatly appreciated.
Here is the part of my pipline which causes an error

.pre-deploy:
  image: dtzar/helm-kubectl:latest
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - k8s
  before_script:
    - |
      GREEN='\033[0;32m'
      NC='\033[0m'
      if kubectl get ns "$NAMESPACE"; then
          echo -e "${GREEN}namespace for project already exists${NC}"
      else
          echo -e "${GREEN}creating namespace for project${NC}"
          kubectl create namespace "$NAMESPACE"
          echo
      fi
    - *kubectl_secret_fallback
    - wget https://github.com/a8m/envsubst/releases/download/v1.4.2/envsubst-Linux-x86_64 
    - chmod +x envsubst-Linux-x86_64
    - mv envsubst-Linux-x86_64 /bin/envsubst
  script:
    - envsubst < ${CHART_PATH}/values.${ENVIRONMENT}.yaml > ${CHART_PATH}/values_deploy.${ENVIRONMENT}.yaml
    - helm upgrade -n ${NAMESPACE} ${PROJECT_NAME} ${CHART_PATH} --install --atomic -f ${CHART_PATH}/values_deploy.${ENVIRONMENT}.yaml --debug


Also, using helm revert caused another issue
ready.go:303: [debug] Deployment is not ready: com-front-dev/client-deployment. 0 out of 1 expected pods are ready


Before accessing the shell of the containers, have you checked the corresponding pods logs? Or other errors/issues at the cluster or node level, like not having enough resources to create the pod(s) and waiting for a new node to be available?

@RuiJarimba im not familiar with kubernetes, to be honest dont know how to, i know there is an issue with the code itself, it cannot build due to error in syntax, can this cause this issue?

I'd recommend you to install Open Lens in case you haven't done it yet - it's a very useful tool to manage and troubleshoot issues in Kubernetes clusters.

This question is similar to: Helm upgrade not possible. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Alternative dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65006907/kubernetes-helm-stuck-with-an-update-in-progress
